# How can i add variable value to sendgrid mail body in python

Tags: python, html, sendgrid

#in the below "html_content" i want to display variance_count_gw value,  duplicate_count_gw  which #will vary.

```
variance_count_gw = 3100
duplicate_count_gw = 200

# If variance_count greater than 3000 or duplicate_count greater than 1000, then trigger mail

import os, requests, urllib, json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email='a@xyz.com',
    to_emails=['b@ght.com'],
    subject='Variance/Duplicate count status',
    html_content='<strong>here it should be 3100 and 200</strong>')

sg = SendGridAPIClient('value') 


if variance_count_gw > 3000 or duplicate_count_gw > 1000 :
      sg.send(message)
```

Comment: did you tried : html_content='<strong>here it should be '+str(variance_count_gw )+' and ' str(duplicate_count_gw )+' </strong>')

Comment: Hey @NirElbaz, make that a real answer so that I can up vote it properly!

Comment: @philnash Done and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
html_content='<strong>here it should be '+str(variance_count_gw )+' and ' +str(duplicate_count_gw )+' </strong>')
```